# How to write a shell command to make a header of a txt file

Tags: shell

I want a simple shell command to move a line  beginning "HEADER_TOP" which occurs somewhere in a file called file.txt to the top of the file. I know I should grep the name, delete that line and add it back as the first line but I am unsure of the sequence of commands that I should use

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
{ grep HEADER_TOP file.txt; grep -v HEADER_TOP file.txt; } > file.tmp &&
mv file.tmp file.txt
```

Or use a scriptable editor:

```
ed file.txt <<ED_COMMANDS
/^HEADER_TOP/m0
wq
ED_COMMANDS
```

That finds the line you're looking for, `m`oves it to the top of the file, and saves the file.